# What is an overlay?

Tags: ros, overlay

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to linux and ROS. Installed ROS successfully and currently following the tutorial. It mentioned in the tutorial "overlay". Could anyone pls brief explain what it is?

Thank you

Jack

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43564/what-is-an-overlay?/) by [Jackie](https://answers.ros.org/users/3171/jackie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 103 on 2012-09-10

Post score: 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When installing ROS in Ubuntu from Debian packages, all packages are installed in /opt/ros/... and owned by root. That allows you to use them but not to change any source code or have additional custom packages that are compiled from source. An overlay is essentially a directory somewhere in the user's home directory that contains additional ROS packages. It is basically the user's workspace.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 13

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-09-11**:
See also: http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Overlays